# How to convert Varchar2 to time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 columns in my table both of varchar2. I have a query like

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN_TIME||' '||MYCOLUMN_TIME_AMPM 
FROM MYTABLE
```

I am getting output **0910 am**. I have tried

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MYCOLUMN_TIME,'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss')||' '||MYCOLUMN_TIME_AMPM 
FROM MYTABLE
```

With this query I am getting Output **09:10:00 pm**.

I want Output like **21:10:00 pm**. How can we achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Can anyone give any hint regarding that. I am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `HH24` format mask, `21` hours equals `9 PM`. There's no point in having `PM` along with `21`, is there?

When you convert a string (0910) concatenated with am/pm to a date, you use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask. Date values - in Oracle - contain both date and time component (see `datum_1` in the following example). Then apply `TO_CHAR` to such a result in order to display it as you want (again, by applying desired format mask) - that's `datum_2`.

For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi pm';

Session altered.

SQL> with mytable (mycolumn_time, mycolumn_time_ampm) as
  2    (select '0910', 'am' from dual union all
  3     select '1150', 'pm' from dual
  4    )
  5  select mycolumn_time,
  6         mycolumn_time_ampm,
  7                 to_date(mycolumn_time ||' '||mycolumn_time_ampm, 'hhmi pm')             datum_1,
  8         --
  9         to_char(to_date(mycolumn_time ||' '||mycolumn_time_ampm, 'hhmi pm'), 'hh24:mi') datum_2
 10  from mytable;

MYCO MY DATUM_1             DATUM_2
---- -- ------------------- -------
0910 am 01.09.2020 09:10 AM 09:10
1150 pm 01.09.2020 11:50 PM 23:50

SQL>
```

---

If you add `PM` format mask, you'd get

```
  <snip>
  9         to_char(to_date(mycolumn_time ||' '||mycolumn_time_ampm, 'hhmi pm'), 'hh24:mi pm') datum_2
 10  from mytable;                                                                        ^^
                                                                                          here
MYCO MY DATUM_1             DATUM_2
---- -- ------------------- --------
0910 am 01.09.2020 09:10 AM 09:10 AM
1150 pm 01.09.2020 11:50 PM 23:50 PM

SQL>
```

but - as I previously said - it doesn't make sense. There's no e.g. `23:50 AM`, but it makes perfect sense in `11:50 AM` or `11:50 PM`.

Comment: Your query is working fine if i use it having WITH clause, but if i use my query as  ```select to_char(to_date(column_time||' '||column_time_ampm, 'hhmi pm'), 'hh24:mi pm') datum_2  from mytable``` it gives me error ORA-1849

Comment: This error means that *hour must be between 1 and 12*, while - in your table - it is not. Find such values and fix them.

Comment: Yes query is correct. Issue was related with my table data. thanks